# In nexus 7 (OS 5.0), drop down showing grayed out and no css style supporting

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, webview, nexus-7

I'm using webview for my app and that working fine for android devices.
Recently I do see a issue with drop down on Nexus devices that it shows grayed out list of option.
I applied the css style like:

```
select option{
color:#000;
background:#555;
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Also created a class in css like:

```
.customoption{
color:#000;
-webkit-appearance:none;
background:#555;
}
```

and applied as:

```
<select>
<option class="customoptoin">xyz</option>
</select>
```

But no changes taking place for nexus drop down and shows same in behaviour. 
Could any one please help me on this?